# How to convert wide to long format with hourly values and datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm retrieving data from a fixed SQL schema in long format and want to convert it to wide format.

As a complication each row in the DataFrame represents the values for a product for a day. Values are stored in columns representing particular hours of the day. The example below shows an intervall length of six hours. This means we store four values per day at 00:00, 06:00, 12:00 and 18:00.The DataFrame looks like this:

```
      id        date  0000  0600  1200  1800
 0  APPL  01.01.2014    12    15    17    19
 1  APPL  02.01.2014    21    23    25    27
 2  MSFT  01.01.2014     1     2     3     4
 3  MSFT  02.01.2014     5     6     7     8
```

The DataFrame i want to achieve in wide format is:

```
                     APPL  MSFT
2014-01-01 00:00:00    12     1
2014-01-01 06:00:00    15     2
2014-01-01 12:00:00    17     3
2014-01-01 18:00:00    19     4
2014-01-02 00:00:00    21     5
2014-01-02 06:00:00    23     6
2014-01-02 12:00:00    25     7
2014-01-02 18:00:00    27     8
```

I've tried various combinations of pivot, un/stack and set_index to achive the target structure but failed. The closest i get to is by using:

```
df = src.set_index(['date','id']).stack()
```

which returns:

```
date        id        
01.01.2014  APPL  0000    12
                  0600    15
                  1200    17
                  1800    19
02.01.2014  APPL  0000    21
                  0600    23
                  1200    25
                  1800    27
01.01.2014  MSFT  0000     1
                  0600     2
                  1200     3
                  1800     4
02.01.2014  MSFT  0000     5
                  0600     6
                  1200     7
                  1800     8
```

But know i'm not able to resolve the MultiIndex.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = """      id        date  0000  0600  1200  1800
 0  APPL  01.01.2014    12    15    17    19
 1  APPL  02.01.2014    21    23    25    27
 2  MSFT  01.01.2014     1     2     3     4
 3  MSFT  02.01.2014     5     6     7     8"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.set_index(["id", "date"]).stack().unstack(0)

def f(key):
    date, hour = key
    time = "{} {}:{}:00".format(date, hour[:2], hour[2:])
    return pd.to_datetime(time, dayfirst=True)

df.index = df.index.map(f)
print df
```

output:

```
id                   APPL  MSFT
2014-01-01 00:00:00    12     1
2014-01-01 06:00:00    15     2
2014-01-01 12:00:00    17     3
2014-01-01 18:00:00    19     4
2014-01-02 00:00:00    21     5
2014-01-02 06:00:00    23     6
2014-01-02 12:00:00    25     7
2014-01-02 18:00:00    27     8
```